# Genitiv Eigennamen

Tags: genitive

Wie kann man im Deutschen *von Anna und Peter* durch Genitiv ausdrücken?

> Am Samstag war ich auf/bei der Hochzeit **von Anna und Peter**.

Mir ist nämlich unklar, welche der beiden folgenden Versionen korrekt ist:

- Genit-s nur beim letzen Namen (wie auch im Englischen üblich)

  > Am Samstag war ich auf/bei **Anna und Peters** Hochzeit.
- Genit-s bei bieden Namen

  > Am Samstag war ich auf/bei **Annas und Peters** Hochzeit.

Comment: Was wäre mit "Annas und Peters Hochzeit" ein Problem?

Comment: Beta: Fragen Sie mich, ob's ein Problem wäre? Das weiß ich nicht genau, deswegen frage ich ja die Community...

Comment: Bitte erkläre was du hier als problematisch auffasst, sonst riskiert die Frage als Off-Topic behandelt zu werden. Ist deine Frage darüber ob beide Namen ein Genitiv-S haben soll, oder über etwas anders?

Comment: Ich verstehe ehrlich gesagt nicht, was Ihnen in meiner Formulierung unklar ist. Ich wollte wissen, ob man „von Anna und Peter“ durch Genitiv wiedergeben kann, wie man es z.B. im Englischen machen kann: „Anna and Peter's …“ Aber ich weiß nicht, wie man es sagen kann – ob „s“ nur an den letzten Namen angehängt wird oder an beide Namen. Hoffe, ich habe mich nun verständlicher ausgedrückt.

Comment: Edit: Eine Hochzeit, eine Anna, ein Peter, ein Ich - kein Plural weit und breit. Man war auch nur ein mal dort.

Comment: @Serena, das ist jetzt in der Tat klarer, aber das sollte in die Frage und nicht in einen Kommentar.

Comment: Liebe Leute, bitte entschuldigt, wenn ich mich undeutlich ausgedrückt habe. Bin neu hier und habe noch Schwierigkeiten mit dem Formulieren (es wird ja eher alles korrigiert ; ) Ich habe jetzt eine tolle Antwort bekommen, daher lasse ich diese Frage mal so und passe bei meiner nächsten Frage besser auf! =)

Comment: @Serena: Ich habe deine Frage editiert. Steht jetzt dort, was du eigentlich wissen wolltest? Jedenfalls habe ich deinen Kommentar so verstanden. Bitte schreibe so etwas in Zukunft nicht in einem Kommentar, sondern editiere selber deine Frage um Unklarheiten zu beseitigen. Noch besser: Gleich schrieben, was man wirklich wissen will, und dabei die eigenen Vermutungen und ein paar Beispiele bekanntgeben.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am Samstag war ich auf/bei der Hochzeit von Anna und Peter.
>
> Am Samstag war ich auf/bei Annas und Peters Hochzeit.

Der zweite Satz kann leider auch wie folgt verstanden werden:

> Am Samstag war ich auf/bei Annas *Hochzeit* und Peters Hochzeit.

Also zwei verschiedene Hochzeiten. Deshalb wird die erste Form bevorzugt, wenn man betonen will, dass es sich nicht um eine Auslassung handelt.

Die Gruppierung wie im Englischen (Anna and Peter's) ist im Deutschen zumindest nicht üblich.

Comment: Janka: besten Dank!

Comment: _»Am Samstag war ich auf der Hochzeit Annas und Peters.«_ Nicht üblich, aber korrekt? Ich glaube schon.

Comment: Da hast du dasselbe Problem, dass es als zwei verschiedene Hochzeiten verstanden werden kann.

Comment: @Janka "auf der Hochzeit von Anna und Peter" kann auch als zwei Hochzeiten verstanden werden, wenn man es so verstehen will. Inhaltlich drücken beide Sätze das selbe aus!

Comment: Ich denke auch, wenn es sich wirklich um zwei Hochzeiten handeln würde, würde man das auch so sagen und gut is': *Ich war auf Annas und Peters Hochzeiten/den Hochzeiten von Anna und Peter*. Im Singular geht man standardmäßig von einer einzigen Hochzeit aus, egal ob mit Genitiv oder "von".